# Крупные проекты на mono

Tags: c#, asp.net, mono

Добрый день,
Какие крупные проекты(сайты) используют mono?

Comment: Вопросы-опросники здесь делать не допускается.

Comment: хостинг на mono = http://www.heliohost.org/home/features/languages/aspnet и чтобы вопросы не замораживали - приходи на наш замечательный сайт http://linuxforum.ru/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не знаю крупные ли, мелкие ли прожекты у компаний из этого списка. Судите сами:
http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/showcase/companies-using-mono/